# can't get Camel unmarshal zipfile working?

Tags: apache-camel, unmarshalling, splitter, camel-zipfile

I have a compressed or ZIP file inbound on camel route. This zip file has multiple CSV files within.  I also need to condition the file content before further processing.  It seems I can successfully unzip the file but cannot work on it is unmarshalled.  It seems that multiple splitters are a problem.  ???  hoping someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong.  If I take the files out of the zip file, I can process them all individually, but I can't process them from the zip file.

I've tried ZipFileDataFormat, also ZipSplitter with same results.  tried .split(bodyAs(Iterator.class))

```
        } else if (Boolean.parseBoolean(isCompressedOnly)) { //Only Zipped or Compressed

            ZipFileDataFormat zipFile = new ZipFileDataFormat();
            zipFile.setUsingIterator(true);

            from(fromStr)
            .routeId(routeId)
            .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "Message received ${file:name} for Only Zipped or Compressed files from host " + host)
            .unmarshal(zipFile)
            .split(body(Iterator.class))
            .streaming()
            .convertBodyTo(String.class)
            .wireTap("file:" + fileArchive)
            .split(body()).streaming()
            .process(new EndpointParametersProcessor(decoderName))
            .to(toStr)
            .end();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

adding tokenize("\n") in the splitter operation that works on the individual csv files appears to have corrected my problem.  also, to rejoin the message records to a single packet, include an aggregation strategy.

```
        } else if (Boolean.parseBoolean(isCompressedOnly)) { //Only Zipped or Compressed

            ZipFileDataFormat zipFile = new ZipFileDataFormat();
            zipFile.setUsingIterator(true);

            from(fromStr)
            .routeId("Zipped.Only")
            .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "Message received ${file:name} for Only Zipped or Compressed files from host " + host)
            .unmarshal(zipFile)
            .split(body(Iterator.class))
            .streaming()
            .convertBodyTo(String.class)
            .wireTap("file:" + fileArchive)
            .split(body().tokenize("\n"), new FleetAggregationStrategy()).streaming()
            .process(new EndpointParametersProcessor(decoderName))
            .end()
            .to(toStr);
```

Comment: Thanks for contributing an answer back :)